# php preg_replace using captured group as array index

Tags: php, arrays, regex

Seems like this should be straightforward but the following code is not working:

```
$text = preg_replace('/test([0-9]+)/i', $array["$1"], $text);
```

The code is supposed to find all instances like 'test1', 'test2', 'test3', etc. in a text and replace with the values of $array[1], $array[2], $array[3], etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want to use `preg_replace_callback()` and pass the array via `use()` to it,

Comment: The second argument for preg_replace takes in a replacement string, which can contain references in the form of $n. These aren't php variables so you can't use them the way you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a callback:

```
$text = preg_replace_callback('/(test)([0-9]+)/i', 
                              function($m) use($array) { return $m[1].$array[$m[2]]; },
                              $text);
```

The function takes the matches and uses the first capture group match concatenated with the array item with the second capture group match as the index.  You might want an if in there to check that `$array[$m[2]]` exists first.

Alternatively you could use a loop:

```
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    $text = str_replace("test$key", "test$val", $text);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Brilliant!

Comment: I have no clue what's going on. Could you please explain what ```$m``` is for and what ```$m[1].$array[$m[2]]``` means?

Comment: $m is an array of the matches so $m[1] is the match from the first capture group ()

Answer (score 2):

You already have the answer. This one is only to explain better than in comments your assumption error.

`$1` is not a result of first parameter, it is a placeholder used **only** by `preg_replace` itself. Your use invoke also the commands precedence.

In other words, if you try this code:

```
$text = 'Lorem test8 Dolor';
function test( $arg ) { echo $arg.PHP_EOL; }
$text = preg_replace('/test([0-9]+)/i', test("$1"), $text);
echo $text;
```

You obtain this output:

```
$1
Lorem  Dolor
```

As you can see, **first** argument is evaluated, **then** the result is used by `preg_replace`: `test()` function receive literally `$1` (and in the same way your array), not the `8` retrieved by `preg_replace`; then `preg_replace` replace matched substring by value returned in second argument: in above case `test()` returns nothing, so the replacement is nothing.

With this code:

```
function test() { return '[$1]'; }
$text = preg_replace('/test([0-9]+)/i', test(), $text);
```

The resulting string is:

```
Lorem [8] Dolor
```

because `test()` returns `[$1]` and it can be used by `preg_replace` to perform the replacement.

In your specific case, the replacement happen only if you have a scenario like this one:

```
$array["$1"] = 'Ipsum';
$text = preg_replace('/test([0-9]+)/i', $array["$1"], $text);
```

The final text is:

```
Lorem Ipsum Dolor
```

This is not your desired result, but — as mentioned earlier — you already have the answer...